# Random name of database

Tags: couchdb

I create a new user in CouchDB this way:

```
curl -X  PUT   MY_URL  / _users / org.couchdb.user:userName 
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d  '{"name": "userName", "password": "pass", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'
```

This method creates two things: document in '_users database' and a database.
     I have a problem with the database because the name of this one is chosen randomly.
The questions:
     How can I set the name of the database when I create a new user? 
Or
     How can I  retrieve the name which was created randomly?

Comment: How comes it creates a database? This should create only a user in _users. Do you use any plugin?

Comment: The action you're performing shouldn't create any database, random or not.

Comment: Clearly he has `couch_peruser` set.  @richard gives the correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if, when generating the user name, you save the value to obtain the hexadecimal value?

The database by users in CouchDB is the hexadecimal value of the user name. Example if the username is john the database generated for this user is `userdb-6a6f686e`.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/couch-peruser.html